# Do multiple measurements on each patient require mixed effect methods if the number of measurements per patient is the same?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, validation, non-inferiority

> *For the purposes of this question, let's acknowledge that accuracy is not the best way to measure a model's performance, and that a proper scoring rule is best.  However, the decision to use accuracy as the measure of interest is was beyond my control and so we are working with what is available to us.*

A team of researchers is interested in evaluating a machine learning model against a gold standard.  The model is a binary classification model (disease absence/presence) and will be used on 50 patients.  Each of the 50 patients will be measured 4 times at 4 different locations on their body. A prediction will be made at each of the 4 locations, and the accuracy of these predictions is of interest.  The researchers are interested in determining if the model's accuracy is *no worse* than the gold standard, suggesting a non-inferiority test for the difference in accuracy.

### Question

There is concern that the multiple measurement may induce a bias due to within patient correlation.  Is this concern valid, and if so how may the non-inferiority test be performed?

I believe not.  Because all patients are measured the same number of times, then the within patient correlation should not be an issue in estimating the accuracy of the model.   Things would be different if, say, one patient was measured 20 times and the others were measured twice or if the individual patient accuracy was of interest.  Hence, this team can go about computing the accuracy of their model (again, acknowledging there other approaches preferred over accuracy) and can perform a non-inferiority test as usual.

Comment: The fact that you are using forced-choice classification in a completely inappropriate setting for it makes the other issues not very relevant.  See fharrell.com/post/classification

Comment: @FrankHarrell You read the part where I said it wasn’t my decision, right?

Comment: Is number of measurements -- and hence predictions -- the only relevant concern? Are these the same 4 locations? Can the location of the measurement make a difference for the accuracy?

Comment: "Not my decision" is not a reason not to pursue a good analysis strategy.  Be brave.

Comment: @dipetkov The number of measurements is the only concern, yes.  Same four locations, each time.  Let's assume the location of the measurement does not make a difference for the accuracy.

Comment: @FrankHarrell "Not my decision" is precisely a good reason not to pursue a better analysis.  As collaborators, we have to know when to lose the statistical battle so we can live to win the methodological war.  I can't just throw my hands in the air and give up when people have a suboptimal analysis, and suggesting "be brave" is not helpful.  It just ignores the reality of working with people who are in the process of learning how to analyze their data.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I have already suggested they report calibration slope/intercept/plots and use a proper scoring rule, parroting many of the points made in your blog posts. The researchers have made their decision have been given the best information available.  If they don't or can't take that path, I don't see why I should own that responsibility and be chastised for it.

Comment: I can only say that over my career the number of times I've backed down and been involved in an unprincipled analysis doesn't require one hand to count.  Jobs for skilled data analysts are too plentiful.